# A somebody or just somebody?

Tags: articles

What's the point in using "a" before "somebody, nobody"?

> I am not a nobody, I am a somebody.

How would it differ from:

> I am not nobody, I am somebody.

Comment: Either or both of the articles can be omitted. It's just a stylistic choice that makes no difference to the meaning, See [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+not+a+nobody%2CI+am+not+nobody&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) showing that it's equally common to include or not include the article in the first assertion. I can't search for the second assertion in the same way because it'll pick up "false positives" like *I am somebody who works for a living*, but I'm sure contextually relevant hits would be about the same for that one too.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a slight meaning difference between the two sentences.

When putting an "a" in front of nobody/somebody, "A nobody" refers to an unimportant, insignificant person and "a somebody" refers to an import, significant person.

In the first sentence, the speaker is clearly saying they are an important person. In the second sentence the speaker could be saying the same, but it could also be interpreted as the speaker saying they are a person, and they have a sense of individuality or something like that.